# Context menu not working when keyup event listener

Tags: jquery, html

I have these event listeners (snippet):

```
...
else if($(domElement).is(':text')){
    $(domElement).focus( function () {
        $(domElement).keyup( function () {
            methods['dataUnsaved'].apply( this, []);
        });
      }); 
      $(domElement).blur( function () {
          $(domElement).unbind('keyup');
      }); 
...
```

They work as expected, but for some reason I can't right click to see the context menu. I have tried returning false, and preventDefault(), but without success.
Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you have `keyup` inside `focus`? No need for `focus` here.

Comment: It's true that it's not needed. There are a lot of inputs, and I figured it would be better to define keyup only when the input has focus.

Comment: No because that will register 2 events for each element instead of 1 :)

Comment: OK. I'll remove the focus event, but the context menu is still not available.

Comment: Try posting a JS fiddle with all your relevant code in so people can help you further http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I tried, but culdn't reproduce the problem on JSFiddle. (The function is inside a JQuery-plugin.)

Comment: Why are you unbinding the event on `blur` and binding it on `focus`?

Comment: Are you sure it's these event listeners that are causing the issue?

Comment: I'm a bit reluctant to keyup-event in general, so i figured it would be good to only have it on one textfield at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I have now found out that there was another plugin with event listeners connected to the inputs. (A plugin for input restrictions, only numeric in this case.)

Thank you for your interest.